# Integration of shiro and oAuth2 module in vaadin application

Tags: oauth-2.0, shiro, vaadin8

In my vaadin application I need to login using facebook and google signin with integration of shiro and oAuth2 module. I tried using pac4j but I'm not able get properly.

Can any one suggest some examples?

Comment: Before anyone suggests, show what you tried. In code.

Comment: I have tried the example from this https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j, here instead of jsp pages i have created view classes only for facebook
but I'mgetting 404 error.